# Do I have to close the Cursor object whenever I call rawQuery()?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm planning to use Android SQLite for the first time.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("some select command here", null);

// some jobs with the cursor..

c = db.rawQuery("another select command here", null);

// some jobs with the cursor..

c.close();
db.close();

c = null;
db = null;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to call rawQuery() method several times.

1. Do I have to close the cursor before I call rawQuery() method **AGAIN**?
2. Do I have to assign null to the variables after closing the cursor and database like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I have to close the cursor before I call rawQuery() method AGAIN?

Close the cursor whenever you are finished reading from it. This is to release resources that are opened by the cursor, so yes, you should close the first cursor before the second query.

> Do I have to assign null to the variables after closing the cursor and database like above?

It depends on the scope of the variables. If your code looks like this...

```
class Foo {
    void doSomething() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = ...
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery...
        // other stuff
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

... then there's really no point nulling them out because they will go out of scope immediately when the method finishes execution. But your actual code might look different. If you have some reason for wanting to allow those objects to be garbage collected, then you can null out the variables.

Comment: Thank you so much Karakuri!