# Simple Android Studio Mistake

Tags: android, database, android-studio

This Cursor should be freed up after use with #close()
I am getting this mistake with the word "rawQuery" at getUser. Please give me some advises how to fix this. Thank u very much

```
`class DbHelper(context:Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "app", factory, 1) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val query = "CREATE TABLE users (id INT PRIMARY KEY, login TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)"
        db!!.execSQL(query)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put("login", user.login)
        values.put("email", user.email)
        values.put("pass", user.pass)

        val db = this.writableDatabase
        db.insert("users", null, values)
        db.close()
    }

    fun getUser(login: String, pass: String): Boolean {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login' AND pass = '$pass'", null)
        return result.moveToFirst()

    }
}`
```

Comment: Why do not read some other questions about that "warning"? You could find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886025/do-i-have-to-close-the-cursor-object-whenever-i-call-rawquery